# Mediawiki file upload link not available for any user or administrator

Tags: mediawiki

As a basic user/administrator of mediawiki solutions, using Plesk on th elatest one, I seem not to be able to get people to upload files; the file upload link never appears and the File List remains empty.
On the server, in the file explorer, I have uploaded one image in the /images folder in order to check what works and what doesn't. The File List remains empty.
In the PHP settings, file uploads are on (file_uploads = On).
Open_basedir is set to the /images and /tmp folder (separated by a semicolon).
For both folders, rights have been set to 755.
The user with which the application is executed is also the user created when installing Mediawiki.
In Mediawiki, both admins and users are allowed file uploads.

Is there any setting I forgot to mention or forgot to set?
Should the settings be different, for instance another user account with the right access?
Or is there another reason why the file upload facility does not appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself; in PHP the file uploads were on, but not in the Mediawiki application itself.
I went to LocalSettings.php and found this setting
$wgEnableUploads = false;
By turning that to true, after a page reload I saw "Upload file" under Tools" in the left hand menu.